# Evaluating string “2>4” yield bool false

Tags: c#

There's a snippet in c# can compute formulas from string and return the result like this:

```
using System.Data;
DataTable dta = new DataTable();
var veqaa = dta.Compute("2+3","");
```

Is there a function like that can evaluate conditions, for example ("2>4") returns false?

Comment: have you read the [C# MSDN Datatable.Compute method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx) give examples and explains.. start there first..

Comment: Oh thanks :) @MethodMan

Comment: Never mind reading the documentation; just pass it `"2 > 4"` and see what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it and, more important, everything works properly:

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    Object check1 = dt.Compute("2 < 4", String.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(check1.GetType().ToString()); // System.Boolean
    Console.WriteLine(check1.ToString()); // True    

    Object check2 = dt.Compute("2 > 4", String.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(check2.GetType().ToString()); // System.Boolean
    Console.WriteLine(check2.ToString()); // False   

    Object check3 = dt.Compute("2 + 4", String.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(check3.GetType().ToString()); // System.Int32
    Console.WriteLine(check3.ToString()); // 6
}
```

As stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx), you don't need to use the second parameter, which is a filtering condition. Once your condition is defined in the `expression` parameter, it's done.